# Javascript bullet function / projectile, 2D Game

Tags: javascript, 2d, 2d-games

I'm currently trying to modify this piece of code so that my player is able to shoot. I'm stuck where it is at the moment where the player doesn't actually shoot anything (no image is created on space click, though no error outlined), The missiles only need to travel upwards on my canvas. I would prefer if any answers to this question also give some form of learning as I'm interested in actually understanding how to implement this properly as to just needing some kind of quick fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `setInterval` calls `moveBullet`, the `this` value will not be the bullet, it will be `window`. Try binding the function to the bullet using the following:

```
setInterval(bullets[bullets.length - 1].moveBullet.bind(bullets[bullets.length - 1]), 25);
```

see [This link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) for more info.

Edit: updating with more fixes:

You should show the console in you browser (F12 in most browsers). This will list some errors you are having.

- drawBullet uses `x` and `y` that aren't defined. Use `spaceShip.x` and `spaceShip.y` instead.
- newBullet uses `angle`, which isn't defined anywhere
- newBullet tried to use the `movebullet` function. It should be `moveBullet`
- drawImage needs an image, canvas, or video element - it doesn't take a URL.

Edit(2): More fixes
There are still several problems to fix.

- One is that you still haven't changed the call to ctx.drawImage to pass an image element rather than a URL.
- Another is your move function is multiplying the x and y values by the speed. That means that as soon as the bullet moves, it is off the screen.
- A third problem is that the `render` function updates the entire background, which means that the bullet, even if it was drawn would immediately get overwritten. You should move the actual bullet drawing to the render function.

I have updated your original JSFiddle with some of these fixes, enough to get it drawing (without erasing). You can find it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/The_Dark/2NZbL/4/). I also changed it to just have 1 bullet per space press (to help with debugging).

At the moment, I just made it stop drawing the background, so that you can see the bullet, but you should look at moving the bullet drawing (not moving) to the render function.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and It didn't change the problem I'm facing, though it could of been part of it. http://jsfiddle.net/2NZbL/ <- This is a Jsfiddle with the full code.

Comment: Thanks for the update, To clarify on the last point are you suggesting that I need to add a ctx.drawImage for my bullets in my render function?

Comment: No, you already have a call to ctx.drawImage in your moveBullet function, but its parameters are incorrect.

Comment: Okay Fixed the issues I was facing, Now I'm receiving an error that my object bullets has no push method which I gather is an array method, Any suggestions on how to fix this? I have tried adding brackets between the passed variables.

Comment: You need to declare bullets as an array somewhere. It isn't declared in your JsFiddle - I fixed when I was trying it, but forgot to write it down.

Comment: After adding an array into my code I'm still not able to see the image being shot and now there's no error coming from the console :/ any thoughts? http://jsfiddle.net/7PLbL/

Comment: The code in that fiddle sets `bullets` to a new bullet item, then immediately sets it to an empty array, then tries to push the array to the end of itself. I can't see that working. You need to declare `bullets` at the same spot as spaceShip to keep it global. Then change your code back to using `bullet` as the local variable that holds your new bullet. `bullets` and `bullet` are two different things. Maybe update/clone your original JSFiddle so the HTML etc is still there.

Comment: I've been fiddling on my main copy for ages now, Been trying to look for articles or anything that might be able to help me understand how this all works. I'm new to JavaScript and I'm finding it hard to find the materials that help you learn all this. Regards, http://jsfiddle.net/8QsMr/1/

Comment: It's still not working but I felt due to the amount of effort you put in to help troubleshoot the issue you deserved the extra reputation, Still hard at work trying to figure out the problems. :)